# Imagem pisca no Chrome

Tags: php, html, google-chrome

Carrego um arquivo PHP que me traz uma imagem em jpg. Código:

```
<?php
$url = "http://site.com.br/sistema/";
?>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#load_tweets').load('arquivo.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 1000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
</script>

<div id="load_tweets">
</div>
```

arquivo.php está assim:

```
<?php
$conecta = mysql_connect('localhost','teste','teste')or die(mysql_error());
$banco = mysql_select_db('nomeBanco');

$selecionaTabela = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE id = '187'")or die(mysql_error());
$dados = mysql_fetch_array($selecionaTabela);
?>

<img src="modulos/upload/<?php echo $dados['fotoEvento'];?>" alt=""/>
```

Mas no Chrome a imagem fica piscando, já no Mozilla não!

Comment: É igual a timeline do Facebook, quando publica algo, aparece a foto da pessoa que publicou a notícia, e o conteúdo em baixo...mas a foto da pessoa fica piscando no Chrome

Comment: Eu coloquei um ORDER BY id DESC...quando vier notícias novas, vai aparecendo em primeiro lugar, igual a timeline do Facebook. É um sistema de timeline que eu criei, mas o problema é que a imagem do perfil da pessoa que publicou a notícia, fica piscando no Chrome. Pisca por que foi definido  1000 milliseconds

Comment: Essas id está vindo de uma única tabela do mysql chamada (noticas) tudo que for cadastrado nessa tabela, vai aparecer na timeline

Comment: Seja como for, não substitua todo o conteúdo da div `#load_tweets` uma vez por segundo. Busque apenas conteúdo novo, e insira no final da div *se houver*. Isso deve resolver o problema. Também recomendo usar um intervalo maior que 1 segundo para verificação.

Comment: Desculpa a ignorância, mas como posso saber se existe um novo conteúdo cadastro nessa tabela?

Comment: Depende da estrutura da sua tabela. Se você tiver um campo de data/hora, pode se basear nele. Ou um id único para cada linha da tabela. Obs: vou apagar alguns dos meus comentários antigos, pra dar uma limpada na pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Seja como for, não substitua todo o conteúdo da div #load_tweets uma vez por segundo. Busque apenas conteúdo novo, e insira no final da div se houver.

Não sei extamente qual o propósito de sua aplicação, mas o mais comum é extamente o que **bfavaretto** falou: exibir apenas conteúdo novo. Para isso:

1) Sempre que um conteúdo novo for inserido no banco grave a **data de inserção**.

2) A cada acesso ao "arquivo.php" **grave na sessão do usuário a data/hora de acesso**.

As informações 1 e 2 vão permitir a você saber quando o conteúdo foi inserido e qual foi a última vez que o usuário carregou os conteúdos. Basta consultar apenas conteúdos cuja data de inserção seja maior que a data que o usuário carregou os conteúdos pela ultima vez.

Ex:

```
$ultimaVisita = empty($_SESSION['ultimaVisita'])?'0000-00-00 00:00:00':$_SESSION['ultimaVisita'];


$selecionaTabela = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE id = '187' AND data_insersao > '".$ultimaVisita."'")or die(mysql_error());
$dados = mysql_fetch_array($selecionaTabela);

$_SESSION['ultimaVisita'] = Date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Obrigado a todos!!! Consegue resolver a parada ai!!! Valeu mesmo!!!